# Help with Changing loop.php?

Tags: loop

I'm trying to edit the loop so if its on category ID 60 it displays "Photos" instead of "Blog".. how do I do this?

blog

```
    <?php if(is_archive()&&!is_category()&&!is_tag()&&!is_search()){ ?>

        <!-- BEGIN .archive-title -->
        <h1 class="page-title">

            <?php if ( is_day() ) : ?>
                    <?php printf( __( 'Daily Archives: %s'), get_the_date()); ?>
                <?php elseif ( is_month() ) : ?>
                    <?php printf( __( 'Monthly Archives: %s'), get_the_date( 'F Y' )); ?>
                <?php elseif ( is_year() ) : ?>
                    <?php printf( __( 'Yearly Archives: %s'), get_the_date( 'Y' )); ?>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?php _e( 'Blog Archives'); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <!-- END .archive-title -->
        </h1>

    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php if( is_archive() && is_category() && !is_tag() && !is_search() ): ?>

    <!-- BEGIN .archive-title -->
    <h1 class="page-title">

        <?php if ( is_day() ): ?>
                <?php printf( __( 'Daily Archives: %s' ), get_the_date() ); ?>
            <?php elseif ( is_month() ): ?>
                <?php printf( __( 'Monthly Archives: %s' ), get_the_date( 'F Y' ) ); ?>
            <?php elseif ( is_year() ): ?>
                <?php printf( __( 'Yearly Archives: %s' ), get_the_date( 'Y' ) ); ?>
            <?php elseif ( is_category(60) ): ?>
                <?php _e( 'Photos' ); ?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php _e( 'Blog Archives' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <!-- END .archive-title -->
    </h1>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: the whole shown code starts with `!is_category()`. so you are checking for category60 in a part of the code that is never accessed for category archives.

Comment: Well spotted. Updated answer

Answer (score 2):

```
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php if( is_category( 60 ) ) : ?>
            <?php _e( 'Photos' ) ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php _e( 'Blog Archives'); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Try something like this.